# Facebook GraphRequest for Swift 5 and Facebook SDK 5

Tags: swift, facebook-graph-api

I recently updated all my `pods` and swift language to `Swift 5` in my project and got a ton of error messages which I have slowly addressed.

I am however struggling with this one, the Facebook `GraphRequest` was working perfectly before, in particular this error message is on the `version` parameter of the `GraphRequest`.

[image]

And if I remove the `version` parameter I then get this error:

[image]

```
func fetchFacebookAttributes(fetchFBAttrbComplete: @escaping (Bool, String) -> ()){


        let graphRequestConnection = GraphRequestConnection()

        let graphRequest = GraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, email, name, picture.type(large), first_name, last_name, gender, birthday"], tokenString: AccessToken.current?.tokenString, version: .defaultVersion , httpMethod: .get)

        graphRequestConnection.add(graphRequest) { (httpResponse, result) in 

            switch result {

            case .success(response: let response)://handling .success response case

                guard let responseDictionary = response.dictionaryValue else { return }


                //parse response code here...


            case .failed(let error):

                print (error)
                fetchFBAttrbComplete(false, "")
                break

            }//end switch

        }//end graphRequestConnection

        graphRequestConnection.start()//start connection


    }//end func
```

I have come across this FB documentation that shows an example of how to use it, but I am struggling to understand how that is used also? is this meant to be a separate file?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/graph/

Comment: Have you tried replacing "version" with "apiVersion" as described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/reference/structs/graphrequest.html ?

Comment: Doesn't work and when i declare a new GraphRequest it automatically reverts to these parameters rather than the ones on that link `let graphReq = GraphRequest(graphPath: String, parameters: [String : Any], tokenString: String?, version: String?, httpMethod: HTTPMethod)`

Comment: In that case you could use this method FBSDKSettings.graphAPIVersion() to retrieve the default Graph API version

Answer (score 2):

Try this for Swift 5:

```
let graphRequest = GraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, email, name, picture.type(large)"], tokenString: AccessToken.current?.tokenString, version: Settings.defaultGraphAPIVersion, httpMethod: HTTPMethod.get)
```